# Minifcar arquivos .JS e CSS em massa

Tags: javascript, css, compressão

Galera, gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem alguma ferramenta capaz de minificar arquivos em `js` e `css` em massa, são diversos arquivos em uma pasta principal espalhados em centenas de subpastas, estou utilizando `Node.js` aonde tenho vários módulos nestas subpastas, e gostaria de minificar os arquivos possíveis afim de melhorar o processamento final do app.

Comment: Você quer minificar arquivos para Node.JS? Não sei se isso faz sentido. A minificação é feita para reduzir os arquivos afim de reduzir o tamanho das mensagens HTTP em um site. Com Node esses arquivos não são carregados via HTTP.

Comment: Então, quero sim minificar para o Node.JS e sim, ele me ajudaria, o node leva um tempo para descompactar o pacote, nesse pacote está o sistema como por exemplo imagens, js e css, atualmente minha pasta modules está com 40 megas isso porque tem varios arquivos javascript, eu conseguindo minificar e tirando os comentários nos js, eu vou conseguir reduzir o tempo de processamento para iniciar meu app, atualmente leva cerca de 20 segundos para iniciar, reduzindo o tamanho dos arquivos consequentemente melhoro o desempenho.

Answer (score 3):

Depende de que framework Web esta usando com Node.js, se for Express (o mais comum) existem os:

### express-minify

Para instalar use:

```
npm install express-minify
```

Ele combina tudo em e envia para a resposta da requisição:

```
app.use(minify());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.get('/tudo.min.js', function(req, res)
{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    res.end(responseJS);
});
```

Poderia requisitar assim: `<script src="/tudo.min.js"></script>`, ele também tem cache desta versão combinada dos arquivos:

- mais detalhes em https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify

### express-minify-plus

É uma modificação do `express-minify`, para instalar use:

```
npm i express-minify-plus
```

- fonte https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify-plus

Comment: Opa, vou fazer um teste, porém não sei se vai funcionar no meu caso, já que os modulos se comunicam utilizando por caminhos, mas farei o teste para ver se é isso mesmo.

Comment: @Patrique "caminhos" deve ser as rotas que se refere do Express né? Se for o caso é facil, usa o `app.get` como no exemplo que postei ;)