# Existe algum problema em comprimir o CSS?

Tags: css

Andei reparando que alguns sites possuem o CSS comprimido, acredito que isso sirva somente para carregar páginas mais rapidamente, tem algum risco em fazer isso? porque tem alguns sites que utilizam o CSS normal, imagino que se não tivesse algum problema em comprimir todos os sites seriam assim.

Então, tem algum tipo de critério para comprimir ou não o CSS? e isso realmente da muita diferença no carregamento de páginas?

Comment: Dependendo da quantidade de elementos que seu css tem faz diferença sim no carregamento de página. Fazendo uma analogia , o arquivo comprimido é indexado fazendo assim a busca por elementos mais rápido e a não comprimida é uma  leitura sem index. Além de ser mais organizado :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Tem algum risco em fazer isso?

Não consigo imaginar algum risco direto em comprimir o arquivo CSS, pois é exatamente o mesmo código, sem todos os caracteres desnecessários mantendo a sintaxe correta. Se seu código CSS funciona perfeitamente, o comprimido irá funcionar da mesma forma. O que acrescenta, de forma direta, é a necessidade de se manter dois arquivos distintos: o original, para dar manutenção, e o comprimido, para utilizar em produção.

> Por quê tem alguns sites que utilizam o CSS normal?

Consigo visualizar três motivos para isso: necessidade, preguiça e desconhecimento. Primeiro,    que nem todas as páginas necessitam, de fato, deste nível de otimização. Dependendo do conteúdo da página, não fará diferença para o usuário ou servidor se a resposta levar alguns décimos de segundos a mais para ser transmitida. Se for o caso, para quê fazer a compressão? O segundo motivo é a preguiça. A aplicação pode até possuir certa necessidade da compressão do CSS, mas o desenvolvedor não faz questão disso. Escrever um código fonte descente influenciará muito mais no tempo de resposta da aplicação do que na compressão do CSS, então nesses casos a compressão se torna desnecessária mesmo. O terceiro motivo é o desconhecimento, isto é, nem todo o desenvolvedor domina o protocolo HTTP e não conhece tais técnicas.

> Então, tem algum tipo de critério para comprimir ou não o CSS?

Tem. Seu código fonte está muito bem estruturado, com todas as otimizações necessárias e mesmo assim o tempo de carregamento da página está insatisfatório? Faça a compressão do CSS e JavaScript. Faça das imagens também e crie sistemas de cachê muito bem configurados.

> Isso realmente dá muita diferença no carregamento de páginas?

Não. Faz diferença, mas não será isso que salvará sua aplicação. Como dito, tem muitos outros pontos que devem ser observados antes e que influenciam muito mais no tempo de resposta que a simples compressão do CSS. Você pode fazer, melhorará o tempo de resposta, mas não significa que a aplicação estará completamente otimizada. Se a aplicação trata um grande número de requisições por curto período de tempo, pode fazer muita diferença, caso contrário, não. Dependerá muito dos requisitos da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 8):

**Não é principalmente para o SEO**, reduzir o tamanho e diminuir as requisições ajudam um pouco com SEO, mas isso é o que podemos chamar de um *efeito colateral positivo*, não é nem de longe um *"fator decisivo"*.

> tem algum risco em fazer isso?

Não se a ferramenta ou plataforma que usou para fazer isto for confiável, bem atualizada e testada, exemplo para quem usa `Node.js` e `Express`:

- [Minifcar arquivos .JS e CSS em massa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226877/minifcar-arquivos-js-e-css-em-massa/226879#226879)

Agora se fizer manualmente o risco é o fator *"erro humano"*, é muito fácil cometer enganos, ainda mais quando se tem muitos scripts.

> porque tem alguns sites que utilizam o CSS normal

Creio que seja por não conhecerem e não entenderem como funciona o HTTP e o quanto isto pode influenciar no servidor ou simplesmente por utilizarem ferramentas "arcaicas" que não suportam a minificação automática, afinal de contas fazer na mão é algo extremamente trabalhoso.

> Então, tem algum tipo de critério para comprimir ou não o CSS?

Para produção, se puder sempre comprima e faça o "merge" deles, a não ser que o arquivo de fato seja pequeno e único, para ambientes de desenvolvimento e/ou homologação você pode usar uma versão alternativa que mostre os originais, sem minificação ou compressão, claro que vale notar que compressão `gzip` (veja [`Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding)) é algo diferente.

> E isso realmente da muita diferença no carregamento de páginas?

**Faz sim** se tiver muitos arquivos, ainda mais em questão de bloqueios de renderização, pois o tempo de download será menor.

No entanto comprimir e unificar não são as únicas coisas que irão ajudar, dependendo da ferramenta que usa para o serviço se fizer isto sem ter um sistema de cache você irá acabar consumindo mais o servidor para fazer o serviço de comprimir e comprimir manualmente pode ser um grande problema.

Então, minificar é benéfico, pois irá reduzir o tempo de "download" e melhorar assim o tempo de respostas para múltiplas requisições e múltiplos usuários, mas como disse existem fatores que tem que levar em conta, pois se não pode acabar tendo efeito contrário ao desejado como **se não tiver cache**, falarei isto mais abaixo.

### Automatizando

Você pode fazer o processo manualmente, as vezes, dependendo do site eu faço, no entanto não vale muito a pena se o projeto recebe muitas modificações, no caso o melhor seria usar algo para a própria plataforma, se geralmente usa um framework, exemplos de ferramentas conforme as tecnologias:

- Node.js + Express: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify
- Laravel Mix (requer Node.js): https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix
- CakePHP: https://github.com/maurymmarques/minify-cakephp
- Django: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor
- Flask (python): https://github.com/lmeunier/flask-compressor

### O que podemos fazer além de minificar

Além de minificar e unificar vários arquivos CSS ou JS em um único, removendo comentários, espaços e linhas desnecessárias você pode usar *HTTP Cache* e usar o *304 Not Modified*, como expliquei nesta pergunta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44178/3635 (acaso use Apache, no entanto é possivel portar para outros servidores algo semelhante)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120344/3635

Se não fizer isto e usar ferramentas automatizadas no servidor pode ser que o consumo aumente e até o tempo de resposta acabe sendo maior que o esperado, ou seja a ferramenta se mal usada acaba sendo prejudicial.

### Comprimindo com Gzip Deflate

Servidores como Apache e Nginx geralmente já conseguem fazer isto automaticamente, mas falando sobre o tipo de compressão, geralmente o `Deflate` **é mais eficiente** que apenas "minificar", um arquivo `.js` que tenho normal pesa 63kb, mas comprimido pelo Apache ele pesa 9kb, ou seja ele é 86% mais leve que o normal, para usar isto tem que ter habilitado no Apache o modulo:

- [mod_deflate](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Claro que é fundamental que use isto junto com *HTTP Cache*, como já citei antes, um exemplo bem simples de uso é adicionar ao seu arquivo `.htaccess` (Apache) algo como:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Para servidores Nginx basta adicionar ao `location` especifico o `gzip_static on;`

```
location / {
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_types      text/javascript application/javascript text/css; # mimetypes aceitos
    gzip_min_length 1000; # tamanho minimo para executar a compressão
}
```

Leia mais em: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/

Answer (score 5):

Então, tem algum tipo de critério para comprimir ou não o CSS?

Busque conteúdo sobre - Minification - existe uma vasta quantidade de explicação sobre o assunto.

E isso realmente da muita diferença no carregamento de páginas?

Sim, dependendo do tamanho do arquivo que você irá comprimir, você consegue ganhar ms ou até mesmo segundos precisos no carregamento dos seus arquivos.

Neste projeto Minify que está publicado no GitHub, ele exemplifica, veja a imagens abaixo que os Bytes enviados antes da compressão foi 2,681 e o recebido foi 98,453 e depois da compressão dos arquivos ele reduziu para 783 Bytes enviados e 29,049 recebidos, uma grande redução.

Antes de comprimir

[image: Antes de comprimir]

Depois de comprimir

[image: Depois de comprimir]

Answer (score 3):

Comprimir o CSS ou JavaScript é boa prática no sentido de performance, especialmente para dispositivos mobile que normalmente tem conexões mais lentas, o que melhora é que o navegador faz menos requisições para montar a pagina.
**Por exemplo temos:** 
Uma pagina HTML e com um arquivo CSS **X** e linkado no HTML e temos outro arquivo CSS separado chamado **Y** também linkado, quando o navegador entrar na pagina vai ter que chamar a pagina HTML, arquivo CSS X e o arquivo CSS Y. 
Não são todos os sites que usam porque nem todos os sites mesmos implementam técnicas de melhorar o carregamento da pagina.

Answer (score 2):

É importante sim! Inclusive para o SEO do seu site.

Um exemplo básico disso é no [SpeedPage](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) do Google, ele sempre alerta que é necessário comprimir ou compactar (ou minificar) o seu CSS e Javascript.

Se for pensar em uma requisição alguns *bytes* não fazem diferença, mas e se você tem milhões de requisições? A somatória dessa memória poderia ser economizada.

> A redução de recursos refere-se à eliminação de bytes desnecessários, como espaços extras, quebras de linha e recuos. A compactação de HTML, CSS e JavaScript pode acelerar o download, a análise e o tempo de execução. Além disso, para CSS e JavaScript, é possível reduzir ainda mais o tamanho do arquivo renomeando as variáveis, desde que o HTML seja atualizado de forma adequada para garantir que os seletores continuarão funcionando.

Ou seja, os benefícios:

- Velocidade (pequena diferença mas é positivo);
- SEO, o Google tem maior aceitação nas páginas com CSS comprimido (como dito no [SpeedPage](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources));
- Consumo de memória quando em larga escala;

Acredito que não haja critérios para comprimir o CSS, até mesmo porque a compressão é a remoção de comentário/espaçamentos.

Um bom site para minificar o seu CSS é: [cssminifier.com](https://cssminifier.com/) que inclusive tem sua própria API.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem problema nenhum em comprimir o CSS, e com certeza faz alguma diferença no carregamento da página pois o arquivo fica menor.

Dependendo do tamanho do CSS, acho válido "enxugá-lo" pois alguns Kbytes a menos no carregamento é sempre melhor, principalmente quando acessados por dispositivos móveis que usam planos com quantidade de tráfego limitados.

Alguns sites não comprimem porque não se preocupam muito com isso ou porque a diferença entre comprimido e não-comprimido seria irrisória.

Eu já comprimi um CSS e deu uma diferença de cerca de 5Kb do original. Pode parecer pouco, mas faz uma diferença a se considerar quando centenas de usuários acessam o site toda hora.