# Compensa comprimir (minificar) HTML?

Tags: html5, desempenho, compressão, minificação

Estou minificando meus códigos javascript e css e me deparei com a opção para minificar também os códigos HTML, aí me veio a dúvida: realmente compensa fazer isso?

Vale a pena pela economia de tamanho e aumento de desempenho?

Comment: A resposta é a mesma para [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88058/5878) e [CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227116/5878): tem muitas outras coisas que impactam muito mais na performance que o tamanho dos arquivos. Ajuda levemente a melhorar a performance diminuindo o tempo de resposta da aplicação, mas nada muito impactante.