# meu servidor express não acha os arquivos javascripts e style contido no html

Tags: express.js

olá galera sou iniciante na área, esse e meu prblema: Meu servidor  express não acha os arquivos javascripts e style contido no html esse é meu código:
APP.JS

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("Servidor test Rodando!")
})
```

AQUI O HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alphabet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cores.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

TENHOS TODOS ESSES ARQUIVO JS.MAIS O NAVEGADOR NÃO CONSEGUI ACHAR.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não configurar para acessar os arquivos é claro que ele não vai achar, porque seu código Express só fornece o index.html, não esta configurado nada além disso.

Pra resolver "rápidamente" (sem rodeios aqui na resposta) mova seus scripts, css e imagens para uma pasta chamado `static` e adicione isto ao código:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
```

Tudo que estiver nisto vai ser disponibilizado como se fossem rotas, no entanto para produção eu recomendaria (depois que você estudar bastante e aprender de verdade HTTP) a minificar os arquivos e unifica-los para acelerar a entrega dos recursos, como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226879/3635

Claro que em produção você usa minificado e em desenvolvimento você pode usar normal, ou minificado+source Maps, no entanto isto é muita coisa além do que perguntou, então ficam como dicas para o futuro.